# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Always false in SAML 2.0 using ITFoxtec

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 in my Dotnet 3.1 Project. I am initiating request from server and validating the login till here everything is working fine.

After getting response assertion from server and getting claims transformed and creating a session but still my application is unable to login.

Below are snippets of my code for reference.

**AuthController.cs**

```
 [Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
            var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);
            binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
            if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
            }
            binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);

            await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.TransformClaims(claimsPrincipal),isPersistent:true, lifetime: new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

            var auth = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return Redirect("~/");


    }
```

**ClaimsTransform.cs**

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal TransformClaims(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
        var tenantId = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var Name = identity.FindFirst("firstName");
        var firstName = identity.FindFirst("firstName");
        var Email = identity.FindFirst("Email");
        var UserID = identity.FindFirst("UserID");
        
        
        var claimsToKeep = new List<Claim> { tenantId, Name,firstName, Email, UserID };

        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsToKeep, identity.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.Role);
        ClaimsPrincipal newClaims = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);


        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsToKeep, identity.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role)
        {
            BootstrapContext = ((ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext
        });

        //return newClaims;
    }
```

After all this my application is redirecting back to login page instead of home page of the application with logged in user.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the users identity claim to a claim which exist in the claim set, otherwise the user is not accepted as being authenticated.

If eg. the tenantId claim is the users identity then the users identity claim is `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` in `new ClaimsPrincipal(... ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.Role)`

**ClaimsTransform.cs**

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal TransformClaims(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
    var tenantId = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var Name = identity.FindFirst("firstName");
    var firstName = identity.FindFirst("firstName");
    var Email = identity.FindFirst("Email");
    var UserID = identity.FindFirst("UserID");
    
    
    var claimsToKeep = new List<Claim> { tenantId, Name,firstName, Email, UserID };         
    return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsToKeep, identity.AuthenticationType, ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimTypes.Role)
    {
        BootstrapContext = ((ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity).BootstrapContext
    });
}
```